# C++ splitting string using strtok ignores the last entry

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have the following code that is suppose to split a string and inserting it into an array :

```
 char *t; 
 char *tmpLine = (char *)line.c_str();
 t = strtok(tmpLine, "\t"); 
 int counter = 0;
 while(t != NULL) { 
     tempGrade[counter] = atoi(t);
     counter++;
     t = strtok(NULL, "\t"); 
 }
```

but for some reason the last entry of `line` is ignored and not inserted. also line is :

`string line = "1  90  74  84  48  76  76  80  85";`
NOTE : the spaces are tabspaces (\t) in the original file.

Comment: Why don't you just use a stream extraction operator? `atoi`, `strtok` and all that `char*` stuff kind of grates in C++ code.

Comment: well I knew how to do it this way!! I will look into that soon. but can you help with this ?

Comment: There's absolutely no point learning how to do it with `strtok`. And `atoi` is positively evil.

Comment: what should I use instead of `atoi` then?

Comment: Stream extraction operators, as per my answer.

Comment: working fine for me ? check if your input string is correct or not.

Comment: I agree with ArunMu.  See my answer...

Answer (score 3):

**Your code is so wrong it burns my eyes.**

### What is so wrong?

```
char *tmpLine = (char *)line.c_str();
```

First, you are (unless I'm wrong) casting away the constness of a std::string, which is a very bad idea. Anyway, casting away the constness smells of modification attempt...

```
t = strtok(tmpLine, "\t");
```

And here we are...

You are modifying the buffer provided by the `std::string`, as `strtok` destroys the string given to it.

Bad idea: You are not the owner of the `std::string`'s internal buffer, so you should not modify it (you don't want to break your string, and provoke a bug, want you?),

Back to the code:

```
t = strtok(tmpLine, "\t");
```

Ok, so, you're using `strtok`, which is not a reentrant function.

I don't know what compiler you're using, but I guess most would have a more safe (i.e. less stupid) alternative. For example, Visual C++ provides [`strtok_s`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ftsafwz3.aspx). If you don't have one provided, then the best solution is to write your own `strtok`, or use another tokenization API.

In fact, `strtok` is one of the few counter-examples of "don't reinvent the wheel": In that case, rewriting your own will always be better than the original standard C function, if you have some experience in C or C++.

### Ok, but, about the original problem?

Others have provided insight about alternatives, or even the fact the incomplete sample of code you provided seemed complete, so I'll stop here my analysis, and let you consider their answers.

**I don't know what your code is for, but it is plain wrong, and would be even if the bug you reported (the missing token) didn't exist. Don't use that on production code.**

Answer (score 2):

> but can you give me a quick hack around this? because this is not an important project and I would have to change alot to do it like in that question

No, you don't. This does the same thing assuming `tempGrade` is an `int` array:

```
istringstream iss(line);
int counter = copy(istream_iterator<int>(iss),
         istream_iterator<int>(),
         tempGrade) - tempGrade;
```

But it would be better to change `tempGrade` to `vector` and use the code from the answer Moo-Juice linked to.

Comment: to be honest I was asked to use array in this project.

Comment: istream_iterator is returning an error about being undefined, what library should I include?

Comment: @AhouraGhotbi: Go kick whoever gave you *that* constraint. If it was school related, go kick him *twice*. There is a *reason* why stuff like `<vector>` was invented. Whenever I see BD'ed instructors telling pupils to solve problems with one hand tied behind their back instead of showing them how to *effectively* solve the problem, I feel like... ah well.

Comment: @DevSolar I agree with you but unfortunately as you mentioned my hand is tied back by the instructor!!!

Comment: @AhouraGhotbi: `<sstream>` for `istringstream`, `<iterator>` for `istream_iterator` and `<algorithm>` for `copy`.

Comment: @AhouraGhotbi: You don't need the *hand* for *kicking*. ;-) Seriously though, ask your instructor why he's teaching your class the C style of doing things when his job should be to teach you C++.

Comment: I would but I have already gotten in trouble for telling him that he is/his methods are wrong before and he has purposely deducted marks from my final grade just for that. so i would rather just keep my mouth shut and learn it the right way while I do it the wrong way for him

Answer (score 0):

As other people mention, I suggest you take [the recommended C++ approach to this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/237280/437768).

But I tried out your code, and I can't tell what is wrong with it.  I don't repro your issue on my end:

> 1
>   90
>   74
>   84
>   48
>   76
>   76
>   80
>   85

Perhaps your iteration to print out the loop is too short, or your `tempGrade` array is too small?  Or perhaps your final "tab" isn't really a tab character?

Here's the code I compiled to check this code.

```
#include<iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::string line = "1\t90\t74\t84\t48\t76\t76\t80\t85";
    char *t; 
    char *tmpLine = (char *)line.c_str();
    t = strtok(tmpLine, "\t"); 
    int counter = 0;
    int tempGrade[9];
    while(t != NULL) { 
        tempGrade[counter] = atoi(t);
        counter++;
        t = strtok(NULL, "\t"); 
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; ++i) {
        std::cout << tempGrade[i] << "\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple example showing how to make use of stream extraction operators and `vector` to do this in a more idiomatic C++ manner:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void parse(string line)
{
    stringstream stream(line);
    int score;
    vector<int> scores;
    while (stream >> score)
        scores.push_back(score);

    for (vector<int>::iterator itr = scores.begin(); itr != scores.end(); ++itr)
        cout << *itr << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    parse("1\t90\t74\t84\t48\t76\t76\t80\t85");
    return 0;
}
```